# Komparativ von "daneben" (umgangssprachlich)

Tags: grammaticality, colloquial, comparative

Vor Kurzem wurde mir so etwas Ähnliches gesagt wie

> Patricks Aussage war *völlig daneben*.

wobei *[daneben](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/daneben)* die umgangssprachliche Bedeutung "nicht passend zur Situation" hatte.

Ich wollte dann sagen, dass Claudias Antwort "noch weniger passend" war. Meines Wissens hat das Adverb *daneben* keine Komparativform, d.h., es gibt kein *danebener*. Deswegen habe ich gesagt:

> Claudias Antwort war *noch mehr daneben*.

Das hat mir aber immer noch komisch geklungen, weil theoretisch keine Komparative mit *mehr* gebaut werden sollen. Wie soll man so was sagen? Vielleicht wäre *noch weiter daneben* besser gewesen? Oder muss man in dem Fall umformulieren und auf das Wort *daneben* verzichten?

Comment: Ja, wenn es schon um echte Umgangssprache geht, dann ist die Steigerungsform von *daneben* natürlich *danebener*. Standardsprachlich wäre das natürlich total daneben.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann um ncht zu sagen: am allerdanebensten überhaupt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Man muß die Vorstellung von Steigerung im Sinne von Intensivierung von der Komparation der Adjektive trennen. Die sogenannten Grad- oder Intensitätspartikeln ([canoo](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Partikel/Gradpartikel.html), [grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/111)) dienen dazu, um Wörter und Phrasen verschiedener Kategorien zu steigern (oder abzuschwächen).

> Das war **enorm** *schwierig*.
> Er war **völlig** *aufgelöst*.
> Wir fanden das **ungemein** *schade*.
> Ich beschäftige mich **außerordentlich** *gern* mit Grammatik.
> Sie war **total** *im Unrecht*.

Mir scheint, daß *weniger, mehr* als Gradpartikeln auch Adverbien und Präpositionalphrasen modifizieren können.

> **Weniger** *gern* denkt er an die Zeit nach dem Studium zurück.
>
> Letztes Jahr waren wir **mehr** *unterwegs*.
>
> **Weitaus weniger** *im Blickfeld* ist die faszinierende kulturelle Vielfalt. (*Rhein-Zeitung*, 30.09.2011)
>
> Aber **noch mehr** *von den Socken* war ich, als ich den enormen Preis von 5265 € gelesen habe. (aus einem Forenbeitrag)

Oder spezifisch mit *daneben*:

> **Noch mehr** *daneben* finde ich die Argumentation, dass man besser fotografieren gehen soll, statt sich mit solchen Dingen zu beschäftigen. (aus einem Forenbeitrag)

Es gibt demnach keinen Grund, den Ausgangssatz falsch zu finden.

Comment: _Danebenliegen_ ist ein syntaktisch gesehen anderer Fall, da ist _daneben_ eine abtrennbare Verb-Partikel. Verben können mit Adverbien oder Partikeln graduiert werden (_da liegst du aber ganz schön / himmelweit / deutlich(er) daneben als ..._). Im Beispiel geht es um _daneben sein_, da ist _daneben_ ein prädikativ gesetztes 'Adverb'  Auch Prädikate mit adverbialen Prädikativen können  verglichen werden (_sie ist mehr (= öfter) hier als zu Hause_), aber es muss passen. Auf _daneben_ passt _weit(er)_ ggf. besser als _mehr_. Der Ausgangssatz ist nicht 'falsch', klingt aber nach 'Notlösung'.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Ich habe das Beispiel geändert. – Für mich klingt *weiter daneben* deutlich schlechter (und was wäre dann das Äquivalent zu *weniger daneben*?).

Comment: Für eine 'negative Steigerung' (die haben wir im Deutschen nicht, aber z.B. im Französischen: _moins grand_) nehmen wir '_nicht so + ADJ + wie_', das geht aber nur vergleichend: _Wenigstens war Claudias Spruch war nicht so daneben wie der von Patrick._ - Wir alle sind uns vielleicht darin einig, dass eigentlich '_danebener_' gemeint ist, was aber nicht geht. Die angepeilten Ersatzlösungen kann man mehr oder weniger gelungen finden. Für mich klingen sie halt alle nach 'Ersatzlösung', aber umgangssprachlich ist all so etwas ohne weiteres machbar.

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke umgangssprachlich ist

> > Claudias Antwort war *noch mehr daneben*.

OK.

> Meines Wissens hat das Adverb *daneben* keine Komparativform, d.h., es gibt kein *danebener*.

Das ist korrekt. Besser wäre wohl gewesen die Umgangssprache zu verlassen, und mit

> Claudias Antwort war *noch weniger passend*.

zu antworten.

Comment: Alternativ: "(noch) weiter daneben"

Comment: @mtwde Das wäre eine eigenständige Antwort.

Answer (score 2):

Für mich bedeutet *völlig daneben*, bezogen auf eine Äußerung, wegen des *völlig* eher *absolut inakzeptabel* (ein *No-Go*, ein *Geht gar nicht*) als *unpassend* (*ungeschickt*, *unüberlegt*, *unangebracht*), und 'etwas Absolutes' oder 'etwas Völliges' lässt sich nicht gut weiter steigern. *Unpassend* könnte z.B. heißen, dass eine Bemerkung '*verunglückt*' war, das heißt, dass für eine Aussageabsicht ein Wort gewählt wurde, das beim Hörer negative Assoziationen wachruft, die dem Sprecher nicht bewusst waren und die er jedenfalls nicht beabsichtigt hatte.

*Daneben* als figurativer Ausdruck leitet sich von einer räumlichen Ausgangsbedeutung ab und würde, wörtlich verstanden, '*neben der Situation*', also tatsächlich '*unpassend*' bedeuten. Solche räumlichen Relationen lassen sich in der Tat nicht steigern, eine Tasse kann nicht "aufer" auf einem Tisch stehen als eine andere, und eine Bemerkung kann zwar *unpassender* oder *deplatzierter* sein, aber nicht *danebener*. Um überhaupt einen Komparativ sinnvoll anwenden zu können, bräuchte es ein Vergleichsglied, welches hier in dem Claudia-Satz formuliert wird. Ich denke, dass man Patricks und Claudias Aussagen tatsächlich daraufhin vergleichen kann, welche der beiden *weiter daneben* oder umgangssprachlich auch *mehr daneben* ist. Außerdem kann man das *unpassender* nennen, was sich weiter graduieren lässt: '*viel / weitaus / bei weitem unpassender als ...*'.

Nicht-vergleichend, nämlich als Maximum verstanden (bei vielen Adjektiven ist das als absoluter Superlativ = 'Elativ' möglich), ist *völlig daneben* eigentlich schon ganz oben an der Messlatte. Statt '*völlig*' kann man auch *absolut / total daneben* sagen, bei *in höchstem Maße daneben* sträubt sich etwas in mir, für das ich so schnell keine Erklärung habe, aber *in höchstem Maße unpassend* wäre wiederum okay. Andererseits sind Bewertungen wie '*völlig unangemessen*' oder '*totaler Quatsch*' nicht wörtlich, sondern als emotionalisierende Übertreibungen zu verstehen und sollen eigentlich bedeuten '*sehr unangebracht*' bzw. '*ein ziemlicher Unsinn*'.

Als eine Art Raumpronomen (1) (Wo? *Daneben*.) stehen für *daneben* einige Steigerungs- oder Maximierungsmöglichkeiten nicht zur Verfügung, welche die Duden-Grammatik im Abschnitt "*Der absolute Gebrauch des Superlativs (Elativ)*" nennt (Ausgabe 2006 Randziffer 506, S. 380). All das Folgende kann man nicht oder nur mit Einschränkungen hinsichtlich seiner Standardsprachlichkeit sagen:

- **höchst daneben* (aber *höchst unbefriedigend*)
- ??*schrecklich* / **irre* / ??*furchtbar daneben* (aber *schrecklich / irre / furchtbar heiß*)
- ??*äußerst* / ??*überaus daneben* (aber *äußerst / überaus unerfreulich*)
- **erzdaneben* / **saudaneben* / **superdaneben* - allerdings ginge *sowas von daneben!* (umgangssprachlich)

Derartige Steigerungsmöglichkeiten kann man 'guten Gewissens' nur auf Adjektive anwenden. Man verpasst zwar schon mal Adverbien als Adjektiv-Endungen (*Ich hab die aufe Tür zugemacht*), das aber nur scherzhaft und in der klar erkennbaren Absicht, fragwürdiges Deutsch zu produzieren.

---

Grundsätzlich ist mir bei dieser Fragestellung - wie so oft - nicht klar, ob eine Formulierung für eine konkrete Aussageabsicht gesucht wird (dazu fehlt mir mehr Kontext) oder ob es sich nur um so etwas wie grammatische Kombinatorik handelt (was kann man wie ein Adjektiv steigern und was nicht).

---

(1) Als Wortartbezeichnung existieren in Grammatiken und Wörterbüchern für Wörter wie *daneben* (dafür, damit, dazwischen...) unterschiedliche Bezeichnungen, das geht von *Adverb* über *Pronominaladverb* oder *Pro-Adverb* bis zu *Präspositionaladverb*.

Comment: "und 'etwas Absolutes' oder 'etwas Völliges' lässt sich nicht gut weiter steigern" - das stimmt zwar (wenn man die üblichen Vorbehalte, mathematische Absolutheit in natürlicher Sprache zu suchen, außer Acht lässt), aber "daneben" lässt sich auch mit "ziemlich" kombinieren, und dann kann man es tatsächlich inhaltlich sinnvoll steigern. Davon abgesehen klingen einige der hier genannten Formulierungen wie "äußerst daneben" oder "furchtbar daneben" durchaus akzeptabel.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Du meinst vermutlich, wenn man es mit 'ziemlich' graduiert, hat man so etwas Ähnliches wie eine Steigerung, allerdings auf der semantischen Ebene, nicht als grammatische Form? So gesehen stimmt das. Ob man _äußerst daneben_ oder _furchtbar daneben_ als "durchaus akzeptabel" (= _nicht völlig inakzeptabel_ oder _schon auch einigermaßen akzeptabel_?) sehen kann - mag sein. Bei so etwas stellt sich immer die Frage, welchen Maßstab an Irritationstoleranz der einzelne Beurteiler hat und wie häufig etwas eigentlich nicht Stimmiges produziert wird (vgl. '_in keinster Weise_').

Comment: Keine Steigerung, lediglich eine Verwendung von "daneben", die keinen Maximalgrad ausdrückt - auf die sich dann eine Steigerung anwenden ließe. Davon abgesehen schränkt "durchaus" meiner Meinung nach "akzeptabel" nicht ein, sondern betont nur, dass die Aussage ggf. einer anderen im Raum stehenden Aussage widerspricht.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Wie sähe eine solche Steigerung von 'ziemlich daneben' aus? - Was 'durchaus' angeht: Stimmt. Ich hatte das bis jetzt falsch aufgefasst und das gerade in den Wörterbüchern nachgelesen. Es bedeutet im Grundsatz 'unbedingt, auf jeden Fall', aber ich hatte bis jetzt keinen Anlass, an meiner Bedeutungszuschreibung zu zweifeln. Ich muss dem mal weiter nachgehen. Etwas Ähnliches war mir mal mit 'dediziert' und 'dezidiert' passiert, da hatte ich einen falschen Sprachgebrauch immer wieder gehört und den bei mir abgespeichert.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Nochmal zu _durchaus_: Es gibt ja Sätze wie '_das kann durchaus zutreffen_'. Hieße es nur 'unbedingt', müsste der Satz lauten _das muss durchaus zutreffen_, oder? Möglicherweise ist '_durchaus_' auch ein Autoantonym, ähnlich wie '_allerdings_' = ein Wort mit zwei entgegengesetzten Bedeutungen wie '_frugal_', '_Platzangst_' oder '_Quantensprung_'.

Comment: "Wie sähe eine solche Steigerung von 'ziemlich daneben' aus?" - ich möchte nicht "ziemlich daneben" steigern, sondern nur "daneben". Wie das aussähe, weiß ich nicht, sonst hätte ich eine eigene Antwort verfasst. Mein Kommentar bezog sich ausschließlich auf die Andeutung, man könne "daneben" nicht steigern, weil es ohnehin nur als "maximale Ausprägung" in Verbindung mit "absolut" oder "vollkommen" auftrete.

Answer (score 1):

Es stimmt, dass *daneben* keinen Komparativ (und auch keinen Superlativ) hat, aber streng genommen hat es auch nicht die Bedeutung von *unpassend*. Letztere existiert eben nur umgangssprachlich, und im Gegensatz zu meinen Vorrednern betrachte ich es als akzeptabel, auf umgangssprachlichem Niveau auch derartige, grammatikalisch falsche Wortkreationen zu verwenden.
In einem Gespräch, in dem gehobeneres Sprachniveau erwartet wird, oder gar schriftlich würde ich auch das Wort *daneben* in obiger Bedeutung vermeiden.

Möchte man hingegen einen Mittelweg beschreiten, so kämen nach meinem Dafürhalten Formulierungen wie

> Claudias Antwort war *in noch stärkerem Maße* daneben
>   Claudias Antwort war *erst Recht* daneben

in Frage.

Comment: '_In noch stärkerem Maße daneben_' ist sprachingenieurmäßig konstruiert und schwerfällig. '_Erst recht daneben_' ist okay, aber der Bezugspunkt scheint mir stärker die komplette Aussage zu sein als vorrangig das 'Adverb'; '_erst recht_' funktioniert syntaktisch wie 'auch', mit den Zusatzinfos: Der Unterschied ist deutlich / markant, und: Der Sprecher ist sehr überzeugt von seiner Aussage, und: Die Aussage ist emotional gefärbt.

Comment: @RalfJoerres *'In noch stärkerem Maße daneben' ist sprachingenieurmäßig konstruiert und schwerfällig.* - Das ist beim Versuch, einen Mittelweg zwischen Umgangssprache und gehobener Sprache zu beschreiten, m.E. nahezu unvermeidlich.